# Nx2 matrix of points [x1 y1; x2 y2; etc.], get highest y value for each unique x

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to find an idiomatic way to do this.

Essentially I have an Nx2 matrix of points of the form

A = [3 4; 3 5; 4 5; 4, 6; 7 3]

I'd like my output to be [3 5; 4 6; 7 3].  In other words I would like each unique x value along with the maximum y value associated with that x.

I was hoping there would be some sort of

```
unique(A, 'rows', 'highestterm', 2)
```

method for accomplishing this, but couldn't find anything.  Can anyone think of a vectorized way to solve this problem?  I can do it pretty easily in a for loop, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any single call, like you hoped.  But, it can be done fairly tightly (and fully vectorized) like the code below.

```
%sort by first and then second column
A = sortrows(A,[1 2]);

%find each change in the first column of A
inds = find(diff(A(:,1)) > 0);

%add the last point...because find(diff) doesn't get the last point
inds(end+1) = size(A,1);

%get just those rows that meet the desired criteria
A = A(inds,:);
```

So, this works by sorting the data and looking for the values in the first column that don't repeat.  If there are repeated values, this code grabs the last of the repeating values.  Finally, because we sorted by both columns via `sortrows(A,[1 2])`, the last entry for a repeating value will have the biggest corresponding value from the 2nd column.  I think that this hits all of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[r1, ~, u] = unique(A(:,1));
r2 = accumarray(u, A(:,2), [], @max);
result = [r1 r2];
```